# Find geo-points within multiple zones

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm facing an issue. I'm dealing with a lot of data and I need to optimize my system and compiling all my data in one SQL request.

Let assume those informations :

## Database

### store

- id (INT)
- label (VARCHAR)
- latitude (DOUBLE)
- longitude (DOUBLE)
- radius (INT)

### group

- id (INT)
- label (VARCHAR)

### store_group

- store_id (INT)
- group_id (INT)

## Function

I have a SQL function "DISTANCE" that calculate the distance between 2 geo coordinates in km :

```
FUNCTION distance(:latitude1, :longitude1, :latitude2, :longitude2) {
     return (12733.129728 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((:latitude1 - ABS(:latitude2)) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(:latitude1 * PI() / 180) * COS(ABS(:latitude2) * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((:longitude - :longitude2) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )));
}
```

## Context

Stores are geolocated and belongs to multiple groups.

**I need to count how many store there is within the radius of each store of a group.**

## How can I do that in a single request ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to use PostGIS? It has a lot of really kickass functions that might interest you

Comment: @JimJones I just checked, unfortunatly not possible :s But thank you for the discovery ! Might use it for further projetcs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to state the obvious, using that function you can use a couple of joins to get what you want:

```
select
  s.id,
  o.id as other_store_id
from store_group g
join store s on s.id = g.store_id
left join store o 
  on o.id = g.store_id and o.id <> s.id
 and distance(s.latitude, s.longitude, o.latitude, o.longitude) <= s.radius
where g.group_id = 123 -- the group you are looking at
```

And if you want the count, just aggregate the query above, as:

```
select
  s.id,
  count(*)
from store_group g
join store s on s.id = g.store_id
left join store o
  on o.id = g.store_id and o.id <> s.id
 and distance(s.latitude, s.longitude, o.latitude, o.longitude) <= s.radius
where g.group_id = 123 -- the group you are looking at
group by s.id
```

Comment: Ho ! Multiple joins on the same table, didn't think of that. I'll try and then validate your answer if it worked ! Thank you !

Comment: @ThibaultHenry If you join a table multiple times in a query, make sure you assing a different alias each time.